# add full page scrolling ability to all pages

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, vertical-scrolling

I want to add the ability to vertically scroll through all my pages, so i tried implementing into one of my pages, called the details page, whenever I add a singlechildscroll view it gives me errors and i don't know how to fix it, I've tried changing expanded widgets to flexible and column but nothing works

What I am trying:

```
class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final String title;
  final String name;
  final String description;

  DetailsPage({
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.title,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300.0, // set a fixed height
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        imageUrl,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        height: double.infinity,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        Text(
                          description,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                        Text(
                          'Reviews',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView(
                            children: [
                              ReviewTileWidget('John Doe',
                                  'Great dish, highly recommended!', 4),
                              ReviewTileWidget('Jane Smith',
                                  'Not bad, but not my favorite either.', 2),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is using `Expanded` inside scrollable widget(SingleChildScrolView). You can replace

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      ReviewTileWidget('John Doe',
          'Great dish, highly recommended!', 4),
      ReviewTileWidget('Jane Smith',
          'Not bad, but not my favorite either.', 2),
    ],
  ),
),
```

With Column (already have on parent)

```dart
SizedBox(height: 8.0),
  ReviewTileWidget(
      'John Doe', 'Great dish, highly recommended!', 4),
  ReviewTileWidget('Jane Smith',
      'Not bad, but not my favorite either.', 2),
```

Comment: thank you that works! another issue was getting my image to be scaled, because rn the picture just gets cut off in the box, how do i have it so that image is just resized and fully fits in the box?

Comment: can you try removing `ClipRRect` and add `cliBehaviour:Clip.hardEdge` on top Container